# switch off html wrapping of errors in nginx

Tags: nginx

I use nginx on Ubuntu to forward requests to a `Spring Boot`-driven API server. Sometimes the API returns a body with 4xx and 5xx errors, that the client application consumes. E.g. in the API code I might return:

```
{
  "message": "blah"
}
```

However nginx seems to wrap errors up into some HTML and embeds the response within them. Is there any way to disable this behavior? And is there a way to do it en masse (i.e. for all 4xx and 5xx errors, without explicitly writing them all out with `error_page` for example)

Similar question and accepted answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/629880/disable-html-error-reporting-on-nginx), however that seems to be a bit of hack. I'm sure there's a better way of doing this...

EDIT: Config looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name my.domain.com;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9001;
    }
}
```

Comment: So basically you don't want to return the usual 50x page but this content?

Comment: @TarunLalwani that's correct

Comment: Are the APIs in specific location? If so then you can just disable the error_page for that location

Comment: @TarunLalwani thanks, yes it is in one location (although the config has 3 servers all pointing to different applications on the same physical machine). I've updated the post with the config.

Comment: Please check the answer I posted

Comment: @TarunLalwani thanks. I'll test both given answers and come back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add a error_page directive inside the location

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name my.domain.com;

    location / {
            error_page 404 = 404;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9001;
    }
}
```

What this would do is cancel `error_page` from previous directives set at the http block. And pass the result back to the client as it is. You don't want the codes for which JSON should be sent back to the client in this `error_page` directive.

Answer (score 0):

You can try update your nginx conf and add:

```
error_page 403 /error403.html;
location = /error403.html {
   root   html;
}
```

or for group of erros:

```
error_page   500 502 504 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   html;
}
```

And here you can replace `html` files to `json` so nginx will return json respnse, like:

```
error_page 404 /404.json;
location = /404.json {
    root   html;
}
```

and don't forget put `404.json` (and all appropriate files) into root which is specified in config.

In your config it will look like:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name my.domain.com;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9001;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.json;
    location = /404.json {
        root   html;
    }
    error_page 500 502 504 /50x.json;
    location = /50x.json {
        root   html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i'm not sure I understand this correctly - the json that the API generates is dynamic, I don't want to return some static content in a file.

Comment: But 5** errors are server errors and you can't control them, nginx does it for you... Sow with purpose to customize such errors you have to update nginx config. But for 4** errors you can update your app behavior and handle them from app.

Comment: I disagree, it's perfectly legitimate for an API to throw 5xx errors when nginx's only function is to relay the request and response back and forth. So the said API can have "control" over 5xx, and it should still be configurable as to how that is presented to the client

Comment: @user2393012 Have you ever seen `Bad Gateway`, `Service Unavailable` or `Gateway Timeout` errors? Who replies with this errors? I've written that some errors may be handled by app but to cover all errors you have to deal with nginx errors also.